# access vba copy select statement to array

Tags: arrays, vba, select

I'm a beginner with VBA and I'm wondering how  to copy a select statement to array. how can i do?
ı tried to do something but i couldn't complite.

```
Private Sub Komut485_Click()
Dim a() As String

'Dim a() As Integer
'abc = Me.talep_kayit_no.Value
'MsgBox abc


For sayac = 1 To 5

a(sayac) = "SELECT [3_gh_odemeler].[gh_no] FROM 3_gh_odemeler WHERE [3_gh_odemeler].[gh_no] =" & Me.talep_kayit_no.Value & ";"

sayac = sayac + 1

MsgBox a(1)


Next


End Sub
```

Comment: replace `Dim a() As String` with `Dim a(1 To 5) As String` and remove line `sayac = sayac + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I thought arrays always start at 0 and would therefore use the first position(0) as the right position.

```
Dim intArraySize as integer
dim a() as string
intArraySize =5

redim a(intArraySize) 

For sayac = 0 To intArraySize 

a(sayac-1) = "SELECT [3_gh_odemeler].[gh_no] FROM 3_gh_odemeler WHERE [3_gh_odemeler].[gh_no] =" & Me.talep_kayit_no.Value & ";"

sayac = sayac + 1

MsgBox a(1)


Next


End Sub
```

Comment: 1) what is the point of double incrementing `sayac`? 2) what would be for `sayac = 0` at the line `a(sayac-1) = "SELECT .."` ?

Comment: @1 owww sorry my fault, double incrementing needs to be deleted of course. Good point. Thus remove ' sayac = sayac + 1'

Comment: also `I thought arrays always start at 0` - not actually. [Option Base Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: So in this case it does start at 0, since option base is not set to 1.

Comment: why do you think so? If OP didn't put `Option Base 1` in Q, it doesn't mean that they don't use it

Comment: I think so since `option base 1` is not the most common used statement for beginners in VBA.